# Command to list partitions?

Tags: command-line

I want to list the partitions on my phone - system, boot, recovery etc. What terminal command should I use? The `mount` command just lists mount points.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use one of those:

`cat /proc/mounts

mount

  # free disk space of mounted fs'

df

  # this shows you available devices

cat /proc/partitions`

ps: Lines containing asec are moved-to-sdcard apps (it's each an encrypted volume per app for security reasons)

Comment: Well, that lists only partitions currently mounted – in normal mode: `/system`, `/cache`, and `/data`. But not e.g. `/recovery`, as that's not mounted in normal mode. Once upon a time, `cat /proc/mtd` got you a full list – but trying that on my devices with Android 4.1 yields an empty list only... `cat /proc/partitions` indeed lists all of them – but gives no indication of what's what :(

Answer (score 11):

You can see names and partitions at same time.

If you have an eMMC internal storage :

```
ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/
```

or for me :

```
ls -l /dev/block/platform/7824900.sdhci/by-name
```

It depends of your phone storage. So you can try to know in which folder you have to search.

```
ls /dev/block/platform/
```

Last way to know it, if you have the `parted` utility, just use :

```
parted /dev/block/platform/
```

My output :

```
DDR -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
 aboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18
 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21
 cust -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20
 fsc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
 fsg -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
 hyp -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
 log -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
 misc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
 modem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
 modemst1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
 modemst2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
 oeminfo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
 pad -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
 persist -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17
 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19
 rpm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
 sbl1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
 sec -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
 ssd -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
 tz -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p24
```