# Galaxy S7 - Stock Rom - Stuck at Downloading

Tags: downloading, odin, samsung-galaxy-s7

Thought I'd re-edit to make it clearer:

I have a stock Galaxy S7 that is stuck at the 'Downloading...do not turn off target' screen.

I have tried restarting it via vol down and power, and it keeps ending up there.

When I let it naturally boot after forcing a restart, it ends up at the 'Downloading' screen without the device info in the top left. However if I force it to go into download mode by using the home vol and power button, the info is in the top left corner.

The phone is encrypted and has a security pattern.

I want to receieve the data off the phone like photos voice notes etc.

I've tried with ODIN using the HOME_CSC rather than just the CSC and the other files but it gets stuck and says it can't locate the PIT partition.

Can anyone help?

Comment: your volume button stuck/is wet/short-circuited

Comment: I don't think it's that. I can get into download mode, and prior to it doing this. It was just stuck at the 'SAMSUNG' bit that flashes slowly whilst booting up. I commented earlier on the thread below, I want to try it, but no idea how:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201468/how-to-fix-bootloop-or-decrypt-data-in-twrp/242836?noredirect=1#comment324400_242836

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's strange behaviour as I can force it into download mode and I get the same screen where it states do not turn off target, but when I do it this way it shows the model number, secure mode etc details in the top left. My question really is how do I get the device to boot again so I can retrieve my data off it? I can get to 'Download' mode and I think that's about it...

Comment: if it's a hardware reason fix the hardware. the buttons would be my first suspect. if it's a software issue you can't safe data off it, but heimdall could help to flash stock ROM without flashing userdata. TWRP is useless it doesn't support encryption

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flash stock rom with Jodin3 on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1561912/how-to-flash-stock-rom-with-jodin3-on-linux)

Comment: Hi alecxs, I gave it a full charge overnight as it was completely flat at one point. When the charger cable is plugged in, it shows the battery icon with the lightning symbol, but doesn't show it animating, and it's grey in colour. Once it eventually has some decent charge, it boots up to 'Download... Do not turn off target' but without the info in the top left corner. I can manually boot it into 'Download' mode and then it shows the info of the device in the top left corner.

I've tried to use smart switch, and it doesn't detect the device in Emergency recovery mode.

Comment: ODIN detects the device, and I've managed to find the correct ROM for the device, but fails to apply it to the device, and it sits at 'Initializing' then eventually fails. I wish there was a way to recover this device.

Comment: PIT = partition table (if not readable that indicates bad connection). ODIN will erase your data, that's why you should flash necessary partitions only (no pit, no repartitioning) and keep userdata partition, see very last line in above link

Comment: I am now getting this:
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1401)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> skip file list for home binary
<ID:0/005> param.bin
<ID:0/005> modem_debug.bin
<ID:0/005> Home Binary Download
<ID:0/005> Total Binary size: 3954 M
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> sboot.bin
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)

Comment: The above was after I changed the USB port/ different firmware, BTU from XEU