# How to backup a full stock firmware image

Tags: adb, backup, fastboot, partitions, stock-rom

I'm rocking a OnePlus Nord 2 5G here that just recently came back from assistance because I had wiped the partitions with the IMEI stored in it...

I had made a Nandroid backup, but it didn't backed up all the needed partitions to be able to restore it.
So, I went searching for an alternative way to backup ALL the partitions of the phone. Mainly by the use of **adb shell** while booted in TWRP to gain root access without being rooted + **dd** for the backup. And I've made some [good progress](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-no-root-partitionsbackupper-nandroid-alternative.4366055/) so far, but now I'm stuck.

For comparison, I've donwloaded a **full stock firmware** from a third party, and these are all the files it contains:

```
audio_dsp.img
boot.img
boot_para.img
cache.img
cam_vpu1.img
cam_vpu2.img
cam_vpu3.img
cdt_engineering.img
dpm_1.img
dpm_2.img
dtbo.img
expdb.img
flashinfo.img
frp.img
gz1.img
gz2.img
lk.img
lk2.img
logo.img
mcupm_1.img
mcupm_2.img
md1img.img
metadata.img
misc.img
my_carrier.img
my_engineering.img
my_heytap.img
my_manifest.img
my_product.img
my_region.img
my_stock.img
ocdt.img
odm.img
oplus_custom.img
oplusreserve1.img
oplusreserve2.img
oplusreserve3.img
oplusreserve5.img
oplusreserve6.img
otp.img
para.img
param.img
pi_img.img
product.img
recovery.img
scp1.img
scp2.img
sec1.img
seccfg.img
spmfw.img
sspm_1.img
sspm_2.img
super.img
system.img
tee1.img
tee2.img
vbmeta.img
vbmeta2.img
vbmeta_system.img
vbmeta_vendor.img
vendor.img
vendor_boot.img
```

Now, these are all the partitions I was able to find in `/dev/block/platform/by-name` and backup:

```
audio_dsp.img
boot.img
boot_para.img
cache.img
cam_vpu1.img
cam_vpu2.img
cam_vpu3.img
cdt_engineering.img
dpm_1.img
dpm_2.img
dtbo.img
expdb.img
flashinfo.img
frp.img
gz1.img
gz2.img
lk.img
lk2.img
logo.img
mcupm_1.img
mcupm_2.img
md1img.img
metadata.img
misc.img
nvcfg.img
nvdata.img
nvram.img
ocdt.img
oplus_custom.img
oplusreserve1.img
oplusreserve2.img
oplusreserve3.img
oplusreserve5.img
oplusreserve6.img
otp.img
para.img
param.img
persist.img
pi_img.img
proinfo.img
protect1.img
protect2.img
recovery.img
scp1.img
scp2.img
sec1.img
seccfg.img
spmfw.img
sspm_1.img
sspm_2.img
super.img
tee1.img
tee2.img
vbmeta.img
vbmeta_system.img
vbmeta_vendor.img
vendor_boot.img
```

---

As you can see, I'm missing a couple of partitions:

```
my_carrier.img
my_engineering.img
my_heytap.img
my_manifest.img
my_product.img
my_region.img
my_stock.img
odm.img
product.img
system.img
vbmeta2.img
vendor.img
```

Including `system`, which is pretty strange since it's one of the main partitions.

**I've no idea how to find the directory of these partitions, with their labels, and how to back them up.**

---

These are all the solutions, tools, and similar questions I've already tried, without success:
[How to list all major partitions with their labels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92565/how-to-list-all-major-partitions-with-their-labels)
[Command to list partitions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24119/command-to-list-partitions?newreg=ae09db6d007f4614ac2b168a9eafe877)
[How can I view the Android internal partition table?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5232/how-can-i-view-the-android-internal-partition-table)
https://github.com/for2ando/dump-android-partitions
https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar
https://github.com/dlenski/tetherback
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.partitions&hl=en_US&gl=US
I just obtain the same list of partitions I'm finding, or straight not working / the directories do not exists. *Maybe because it's a MTK device?*

The only app that made a difference is [FX file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx&hl=en_US&gl=US). By going in the "file systems" section I can see the `my_*` partitions and their directory, but no system, vendor, or others. And I'm searching for a command line solution ofc.

I've contacted the user that posted the [unofficial full stock firmware](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/oneplus-nord-2-oxygen-11-3-dn2103-eea-rom.4331695/) on XDA. I'm still waiting for the full response on what specific method he use to extract it, but for now I know he used some root solution, if that could help.

Root solutions are completely fine by the way, just, no "Nandroid" as an answer please.

Comment: All block devices are enumerated as `/dev/block/mmcblk*` or `/dev/block/sd*`. You can check from `/sys/block/`.

Comment: Do something like `grep PARTNAME /sys/block/*/*/uevent`. Or simply use `blkid` command. Partitioning tools like `parted` and `gdisk` also show partition/filesystem labels. Any Linux tool will work on Android.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yeah, the partitions found in `/dev/block/by-name` are all `sd*`. Inside `/sys/block/` though I find many partitions called `dm-*` `loop*` `ram*`, `sdca`, `sdb`, `sdc`, `zram0`, that all point to `/device/virtual/block/`. All without their labels though, so it's not really useful to know which of these partitions is what. I've searched around `/sys/block/` and `/device/virtual/block/` for a while but without success.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Alright, both `grep PARTNAME /sys/block/*/*/uevent`, `parted print all` and `gdisk /dev/block/sdc` listed the same partitions I've already found. But buth `df` and `blkid` commands listed all those partitions + all the missing ones minus `system`. That all points to the `/dev/block/dm-*` partitions. Now `system` is the only one left to find!

Comment: Just realized that I've never searched in `/dev/block` manually aaand found them. Exactly all the missing ones that aren't listed in `dev/block/by-name`, are listed with their labels in `/dev/block/mapper`, `system` included (it's `/dev/block/dm-1`). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Found them!

All the missing partitions are listed with their labels in `/dev/block/mapper`